# Android AES encryption secret key

Tags: java, android, encryption, key, aes

I'm developping an Android app and i wanna do encryption with AES-128.
I use secret key and text with hexadecimal.

I use this website : http://testprotect.com/appendix/AEScalc to compute the AES encryption with the following key :  "c4dcc3c6ce0acaec4327b6098260b0be" and my text to encrypt is : "6F4B1B252A5F0C3F2992E1A65E56E5B8" (hexadecimal).

So the result from this website give me "859499d0802de8cc6ba4f208da648a8f" and that's the result i wanna get.
http://hpics.li/d89105a

I find some code on the net, but a lot uses seed to generate random secret key and i wanna fix the secret key.
Actually i'm using the following code, i think it's the code i need but the result gives me  `D/resultdebug: 72adc67b6d11e1c5fb89ddf5faeb0e030686b91f8bfaf6c41335f08955343f87`
and it's not the same result than the website, that i want.

```
 String text16 = "6F4B1B252A5F0C3F2992E1A65E56E5B8";
    String secret16 = "c4dcc3c6ce0acaec4327b6098260b0be";

    SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(secret16.getBytes(),"AES");
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
    c.update(text16.getBytes());
    byte[] ciphertext = c.doFinal();
    Log.d("resultdebug",new String(Hex.encode(ciphertext), "ASCII"));
```

Could you please tell me what's wrong, thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `ENCRYPT_MODE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not converting the hex to binary, you are getting the binary of the characters not the value that is hex encoded.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks zaph, it solved my problem

I added these two lines on my code :

```
    byte[] text = stringhextobyte(text16);
    byte[] secret = stringhextobyte(secret16);
```

And the function stringhextobyte permit me to transform my hex string to byte array and i get the result needed.